# How show thumbnail titles at Jqzoom

Tags: jqzoom

I want to use jqzoom gallery application instead of magiczoom.
I have two problems:

1. Jqzoom shows the same  title at all zooms. I want to show thumbnail titles at top of zoomed big image. How can I do this?
2. At magiczoom application, there is a small magnifying glass image and "zoom" text at top of mid size (to be zoomed) image. How I can realize it at jqzoom?

Answer (score 1):

If you have several elements to zoom with several thumbnails you have to name the "`rel`" atribute to each group so it can display properly your images:

```
<a href="images/bora/bora1_lrg.jpg" class="jqzoom" rel='gal1'  title="BORA">
    <img src="images/bora/bora1_md.jpg"  title="BORA"  style="border: 5px solid #666;">
</a>
<br/>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './images/bora/bora1_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora1_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora1_th.jpg'></a>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './images/bora/bora2_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora2_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora2_th.jpg'></a>
<a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './images/bora/bora3_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora3_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora3_th.jpg'></a>
<a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './images/bora/bora4_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora4_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora4_th.jpg'></a>
</div>
<div class="example_column2" align="center">
   <a href="images/bora/bora5_lrg.jpg" class="jqzoom" rel='gal2'  title="BORA">
     <img src="images/bora/bora5_md.jpg"  title="BORA"  style="border: 5px solid #666;">
   </a>
   <br/>
   <a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal2', smallimage: './images/bora/bora5_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora5_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora5_th.jpg'></a>
   <a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal2', smallimage: './images/bora/bora6_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora6_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora6_th.jpg'></a>
   <a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal2', smallimage: './images/bora/bora7_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora3_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora7_th.jpg'></a>
   <a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal2', smallimage: './images/bora/bora7_md.jpg',largeimage: './images/bora/bora4_lrg.jpg'}"><img src='images/bora/bora7_th.jpg'></a>
</div>
```